# Host Tomcat7 WebApp on domain behind Apache2 with mod_proxy

Tags: java, apache2, tomcat7

I have installed an application with context `/sampleApp` on Tomcat7 running Linode. I also have an Apache server installed.

I have done some configuration as below, through which I am able to redirect the requests from `www.example.com` to the root of tomcat. But I want to be able to serve `/sampleApp` whenever somebody requests the domain name like `www.example.com`.

Here is the configuration I have done so far:

Included and enabled a virtual host `www.example.com` in Apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

And added proxy support in Tomcat7 server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" proxyName="www.example.com" 
                proxyPort="80"/>
```

I have search SO and ServerFault and Google too but cant find something that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this entry in /etc/hosts?

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

If you did try this:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080/sampleApp
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8080/sampleApp
```

Otherwise:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/sampleApp
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/sampleApp
```

and remove the **proxyPort** from your server.xml

ps: remember to restart both tomcat and apache2

Comment: This still does the same. That is it redirects the www.example.com to the root of the tomcat server. I have now installed my application as ROOT and making use of that. Not much of an elegant solution to use but gets the work done quickly. I will come back to this later. Thanks Vitor

Comment: I eddited the answer...
to add a context you can do:

`code`(ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/sampleApp
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/sampleApp)